# OUTPUT updated records into a FOR XML statement

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xpath

Is it possible to update a table and return the updated values in a FOR XML statement?
Consider the following table of customers:

```
Customers  
Id     FirstNam     LastNam  
 1      John          Doe  
 2      James        Smith
 3      Martin       Jones
```

I'd like to update the FirstNam of the customer with Id 2 to David, and return the result as XML.
I've tried using:

```
UPDATE Customers  
SET FirstNam = 'David'
WHERE Id = 2
OUTPUT inserted.FirstNam
FOR XML PATH('')
```

which, of course, doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?  As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not insert the updated values to XML directly.
If you want to save XML of updated data, then you need to make it in two steps:

Step 1: Use Table Variable and insert the updated data into that table variable (as simple process)

```
DECLARE @Updated AS TABLE(columns..)

UPDATE Customers  
SET FirstNam = 'New_Name'
OUTPUT INSERTED.FirstNam @Updated
WHERE Id = 2
```

Step 2:

Generate XML from table variable @Updated as:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Updated
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Cust')
```

and save it to the place where you want.